# place one iframe on top of another

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two Iframes like this:

```
<iframe src="/page1.html" width="620" height="400" marginwidth="0"
 marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and

```
 <iframe src="/page2.html" width="620" height="400" marginwidth="0"
 marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I want to place the first iframe on the 2nd one, exactly one above another but the first iframe which is on the top will be invisible.

Comment: It sounds like you want help implementing [a Clickjacking attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Comment: what's the point of having an iframe on top that is invisible?

Comment: it's not that, how would i clickjack, i am a student of BS(CS) a freshie, just experimenting around anything that comes in my mind. i don't even have a real site. please co-operate you guys are my seniors. i need suggestions, advices from your guys, that's what seniors are for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried setting the css style to:
display:none;

and then using z-index to arrange them how you want

Comment: Superbb man you are a genious... it's so simple. why didn't i think about it, i am so duffer. :) let me try and will let you know what i get